# Android: Low frame rate

Tags: java, android, frame-rate

I have created an application that holds 7 different mini games. One of these mini games has always run fine, well, it always had some frame issues usually running at 6fps. I ran this game recently and realized the frame rate is now pretty much unplayable. I don't what caused this issue and can anyone recommend a fix to improve the frame rate?

The game uses many different classes to be created, it is a surface view. Copying all the classes here will be a lot of code so I will just post the class that creates the surface.

Any help with improving an application frame rate would be helpful thank you.

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    public static final int WIDTH = 856;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 480;
    public static final int MOVESPEED = -5;
    private long missileStartTime;
    private MainThread thread;
    private Background bg;
private Player player;
private ArrayList<Missile> missiles;
private Random rand = new Random();
int score = 0;
private final Context context;

public GamePanel(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    this.context = context;

    //add the callback to the surfaceholder to intercept events
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

    //make gamePanel focusable so it can handle events
    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height){}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
    boolean retry = true;
    int counter = 0;
    while(retry && counter<1000)
    {
        counter++;
        try{thread.setRunning(false);
            thread.join();
            retry = false;

        }catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}

    }

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){

    bg = new Background(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nightskyresize));
    player = new Player(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pilot), 65, 25, 1);
    missiles = new ArrayList<Missile>();
    missileStartTime = System.nanoTime();



    //we can safely start the game loop
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();

}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        if(!player.getPlaying())
        {
            player.setPlaying(true);
        }
        else
        {
            player.setUp(true);
        }
        return true;
    }
    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        player.setUp(false);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void update()

{
    if(player.getPlaying()) {

        bg.update();
        player.update();

        //add missiles on timer
        long missileElapsed = (System.nanoTime()-missileStartTime)/10000000;
        if(missileElapsed >(2000 - player.getScore()/4)){

            System.out.println("making missile");
            //first missile always goes down the middle
            if(missiles.size()==0)
            {
                missiles.add(new Missile(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.
                        missile),WIDTH + 10, HEIGHT/2, 45, 15, player.getScore(), 1));
            }
            else
            {

                missiles.add(new Missile(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.missile),
                        WIDTH+10, (int)(rand.nextDouble()*(HEIGHT)),45,15, player.getScore(),1));
            }

            //reset timer
            missileStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
        //loop through every missile and check collision and remove
        for(int i = 0; i<missiles.size();i++)
        {
            //update missile
            missiles.get(i).update();

            if(collision(missiles.get(i),player))
            {
                Intent i1 = new Intent (context, main_menu.class);
                context.startActivity(i1);
                missiles.remove(i);
                player.setPlaying(false);
                break;
            }
            //remove missile if it is way off the screen
            if(missiles.get(i).getX()<-100)
            {
                score++;
                missiles.remove(i);
                break;


            }
        }


    }
    if(score == 100){

        Intent i1 = new Intent (context, main_menu.class);
        context.startActivity(i1);
    }


}
public boolean collision(GameObject a, GameObject b)
{
    if(Rect.intersects(a.getRectangle(),b.getRectangle()))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
    final float scaleFactorX = getWidth()/(WIDTH*1.f);
    final float scaleFactorY = getHeight()/(HEIGHT*1.f);

    if(canvas!=null) {
        final int savedState = canvas.save();



        canvas.scale(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
        bg.draw(canvas);
        player.draw(canvas);

        //draw missiles
        for(Missile m: missiles)
        {
            m.draw(canvas);
        }

        drawText(canvas);




        canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);
    }
}
public void drawText(Canvas canvas)
{
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(30);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
    canvas.drawText("DISTANCE: " + (player.getScore()*3), 10, HEIGHT - 10, paint);


}


}
```

I also got the log to print out the frame rate, this was the result.

[image]

Any ideas on the cause of this? the fps is the 0.0, this usually would say around 6.0 or 7.0.

This is an odd question, but where I have music it sounds like there is two versions playing over each other, like the application is running two instances of itself. is this possible?

This is the problem

[image]

Comment: Are you running multiple instances of these games? In other words, are you certain the previous mini game has been terminated before starting the new one?

Comment: while I simply just open up the emulator again and the first screen is the main menu screen and this is what plays the music twice after a delay.

Comment: I have updated the question, I believe this to be the problem